# Post Array from React using Axios

Tags: arrays, reactjs, axios

I want to post an array with `axios` into `react`, however it is not working...

The array to post:

```js
[
  {
    "Nombre": "Remera",
    "Precio": "1599",
    "Photo": null,
    "Stock": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "talle": "M",
        "cantidad": "12"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "talle": "S",
        "cantidad": "14"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "talle": "XS",
        "cantidad": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The data posted:

{
"Nombre": "Remera",
"Precio": "1599",
"Photo": null,
"Stock": [
{
"id": 0,
"talle": "M",
"cantidad": "12"
},
{
"id": 1,
"talle": "S",
"cantidad": "14"
},
{
"id": 2,
"talle": "XS",
"cantidad": "6"
}
]
}
Can someone help me on this one?
Thanks!

Comment: can you put your code? maybe there is something wrong with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not send the pure array.

You have to send the JSON as object and add the identifier to your array as below:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Nombre": "Remera",
            "Precio": "1599",
            "Photo": null,
            "Stock": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "talle": "M",
                    "cantidad": "12"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "talle": "S",
                    "cantidad": "14"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "talle": "XS",
                    "cantidad": "6"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {...nextObject},
        {...nextObject}
    ]
}
```